# Elasticsearch 5: BulkRequestBuilder does not accept ActionRequest

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Currently we are building a library Elasticsearch 5 client. BulkRequestBuilder accepts DocWriteRequest rather than ActionRequest in new API. Is there a reason for this change? I see that the new ActionRequest does not accept generic type. Was wondering reasoning behind this decision.

Comment: Looks like it accepts an `IndexRequest` which is a subclass of `DocWriteRequest`: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v5.5.0/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/bulk/BulkRequestBuilder.java#L52 Even 2.4 doesn't use an `ActionRequest` or subclass: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v2.4.5/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/bulk/BulkRequestBuilder.java#L48 Can you share the line of code you are talking about?

Comment: @Phil That's not my question. Why remove class level type from ActionRequest to DoWriteRequest? Want to know the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Which two version are you comparing? 1.7 and 5.x?

Comment: @Phil any 2.x to any 5.x